# Open iframe in new tab

Tags: javascript, php

I want to open iframe in a new tab. Here is the code I am currently using, which does not work:

```
<script>window.open(<?php echo $url[0]->nodeValue; ?>)</script>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<script>window.open(<?php echo $url[0]->nodeValue, _blank; ?>)</script>
```

Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this

```
window.open('<?php echo $url[0]->nodeValue?>', '_blank');
```

Comment: Tried. It opened in the same window. Want to open in new window. Please help.

Comment: Did you put _blank in 2nd param, not same in your code